# Changing main.cpp path

Tags: c++11, makefile, path

I have written a makefile for the following cpp folder structure:

```
-build
  makefile
-include
  a.hpp
  b.hpp
-src
  a.cpp
  b.cpp
  main.cpp
```

and the makefile is as following:

```
IDIR =../include
SDIR = ../src
CXX=g++
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR) -std=c++11

_DEPS = a.hpp b.hpp
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

OBJ = a.o b.o main.o

%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJ)
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean: 
    rm -f *o
    rm -f *~
    rm -f main
```

I want to put the main in a separate folder like this:

```
-build
  makefile
-include
  a.hpp
  b.hpp
-main
  main.cpp
-src
  a.cpp
  b.cpp
```

and the makefile in my attempt to do this was:

```
IDIR =../include
SDIR = ../src
MDIR = ../main
CXX=g++
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR) -std=c++11 

_DEPS = a.hpp b.hpp
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

OBJ = a.o b.o main.o

%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main.o: $(MDIR)/main.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJ)
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean: 
    rm -f *o
    rm -f *~
    rm -f main
```

But I end up only generating the object file for main and others don't compile. Any suggestions.

PS: I want to generate multiple executables and that's why I'm moving the file to a new folder and will add main2.cpp, etc for doing that later.

Comment: Move the `main.o` rule below the `main` rule. Or `make main`. When you just `make`, Make takes the first regular rule as the default.